# RHO in Keras framework

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I use Keras framework for recurrent neural network. I found RHO argument in optimizer (RMSprop) parameter and I know that it is hyperparameter, but I cant find this parameter's description.

What does RHO mean?

link to documentaton
https://keras.io/optimizers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rho is a hyper-parameter which attenuates the influence of past gradient.

See also [this link](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#rmsprop) (`gamma` in this article)